# How can I get the raspberry Pi camera working with c++ on OpenCV 3.2?

Tags: raspbian, raspicam, opencv

I was pleased to read about the addition of ARM support in the Opencv 3 change log, and decided to try installing OpenCV3.2 on my raspberry Pi. The installation appears to have been a success, and works with a USB web camera as one might expect. When I try to use the raspberry Pi camera however, it is less intuitive.

I tried installing some separate APIs for supporting the raspberry pi camera, but this did not pan out. I have tested the camera using separate python libraries (piCamera), and it is operational.

Im not exclusively looking for an OpenCV3 support library, but if anyone has done this type of thing and knows a library that has C++ support for the Raspberry Pi Camera, and works with opencv3, I would like to know.

Comment: OpenCV expects to talk to a V4L device so with the Pi's camera module you need to load the relevant kernel module: `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2` should do the trick. Note: you can't use the camera via raspivid / picamera / etc. while that driver is loaded but you can use the camera as `/dev/video0` (assuming no other cameras are plugged in) which is what OpenCV will be expecting